# SVG: reverse children rotation on parent transform

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

I'm fiddling around with D3.js in this [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/lYWRHmtTZqy9jTATe9pI?p=preview).
It mostly does what I want, but I noticed a small inconsistency.

The idea is that the 2nd slider rotates the SVG elements in the container. As the elements within are actually `text` elements, I would like to have them displayed *unrotated*, and as such, I applied a `transform: rotate` to them with the symmetric value from the slider.

Although, I noticed that by doing that, the `text` elements don't rotate around their center, but rather around their *top-left* corner (I think). This is mostly visible when you observe a point near the edge and see how in transposes the edge on rotation.

I tried already setting both `text-anchor` and `alignment-baseline` to `middle` on these elements, hoping it would offset the `text` path, but apparently it doesn't change the point around which they pivot when rotated.

Additionally, should I try to set the `rotate` with pivot point coordinates, it boggles the effect entirely, by applying some `translate` to the elements, which I can't figure out.

Not sure if `getBBox()` could help me either in this subject, but I've considered maybe offsetting the points by half their width/height. This seems a bit convoluted though, and I was hoping for an easier/more elegant/cleaner fix.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, this is awkward. Right after I posted the question, I found an answer in D3.js docs: [polygon.centroid()](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Polygon-Geom#centroid).

Basically, I used the return value of this function as the `transform: rotate` pivot point coordinates and the offset is taken care of. Example (line 99 of the above plunker, **rotate()** function):

```
(...)
var textElement = d3.select(this);
return justTranslate+"rotate("+ -value+ textElement.centroid() +")";
(...)
```

Hope this helps anyone with the same issue.

**EDIT:** for some reason, Chrome's console says:

> Uncaught TypeError: textElement.centroid is not a function

But the behavior is what I was looking for. Have no idea why.

**EDIT2:** ended up changing the above answer to a `getBBox()` approach, because the slider movement was bonked because of the previous edit error.

Changed it to this:

```
text.attr("transform", function(d){
    var textElement = d3.select(this);
    var current = textElement.attr("transform");
    var alreadyRotated = current.indexOf('rotate');
    var justTranslate = current.substring(0, alreadyRotated != -1 ? alreadyRotated : current.length);
    var bbox = textElement.node().getBBox();
    var point = [bbox.x + 0.5*bbox.width, bbox.y + 0.5*bbox.height];
    return justTranslate+"rotate("+ -value +" "+ point +")";
});
```